# Google Maps API v3: Links (a href) in bubbles are not working within a jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a problem with the integration of Google Maps within a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Links in the maps bubbles (InfoWindowHtml) do not work, they are not clickable. Tested with Firefox 3.6.8, Chrome 9. Unfortunately, it works in the Internet Explorer.

Example: [**http://www.periscope.de/files/jquery_dialog.htm**](http://www.periscope.de/files/jquery_dialog.htm)

If I embed Google Maps outside of jQuery UI Dialog, the links are clickable and work fine.

Is there a problem with GoogleMaps and jQuery UI? Maybe z-index?

Comment: They do, however, work with ⌃-click (or right-click on most machines).

Comment: They are working in Google Chrome!

Comment: Sorry. I tested the "Bubble-Links" within the jQuery Dialog with Chrome 9 and they don't work.

Comment: Do you have 2 same links?I don't see the problem either

Comment: my problem is: In the example google maps integration I can't open the links in the google maps bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

Map and dialog are created from the same DOM element, which is confusing for the browser. A practical approach is to place the map on a child  div of the dialog. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry... I tried it with a child div element: http://www.periscope.de/files/jquery_dialog.htm Still doesn't open the links.